# JQuery form auto submit clicking out side the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to auto-sumbit my form once user clicks out side the div of the form.

I tried the following but it submits within clicking within the div.

```
<div id="formDiv">
<form id="search">
  <input id="target" type="text" value="Field 1" />
  <input type="text" value="Field 2" />
</form>
</div>

// auto submit 
jQuery('#formDiv').live('blur',function() { 
    $(this).children('form').submit();

    });
```

Comment: What if the user does not click outside the div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off-hand, the only thing I can suggest it so attach to the click event of the body, then also attach to the div's click event and `e.preventDefault()` to halt it. Alternatively, you could bind to each form element's focus/blur event with a `.delay`. If they lose focus from one element and aren't in another, submit the form.

**EDIT**

See if this is what you're looking for:

*Javascript:*

```
var queueSubmit;

$('#sample input').each(function(i,e){
    $(this).bind('focus',function(){
        clearTimeout(queueSubmit);
    });
    $(this).bind('blur',function(){
        queueSubmit = setTimeout(function(){ $('#sample').submit(); }, 1000);
    });
});

$('#sample').bind('submit',function(){
    clearTimeout(queueSubmit);
    alert('Pseudo-Submitted!');
    return false;
});
```

*Sample HTML*

```
<div id="main">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div id="main-form">
        <form id="sample" method="POST" target="">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>My Sample Form</legend>
                    First Name: <input type="text" id="first_name" /><br />
                    Last Name: <input type="text" id="last_name" /><br />
                    Telephone: <input type="text" id="telephone" /><br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

[Working Example Here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/75jhX/)

Comment: if i don't use focus, what is the simplest way to submit form when the user click out side the div with out considering the form?

Comment: There's not a good way of doing it, unfortunately. You have to catch a click event over the entire document, but exclude it from the form's real estate.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by putting a click handler on the body and seeing if the event target (`event.target`) is a descendent element of `#formDiv`:

```
$('#search').one('focus', function() { // the first time that a field in #search receives focus
    var $formDiv = $('#formDiv');
    $(document.body).click(function(e) { // bind a click handler to the document body
        if (!$formDiv.has(e.target).length) { // if the target element is not within formDiv
            $('#search').submit(); // submit the form
        }
    });
});
```